# how to set date in Datepicker dialog from edittext android?

Tags: android, datepicker, dialog, android-edittext, fragment

I have a `datepicker` dialog which put in an `edittext` to set birthday .. the dialog after setting the date return the current date .. what I need is to display the date I selected to the `datepicker` dialog after choose it?

The `Datepicker` dialog class:

```
    public class DatePickerDialog2 extends DialogFragment{

public static final String ARG_DEFAULT = "default";

private DatePicker datePicker;
private String defaultDate;

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener onDateListener;
public DatePickerDialog2() {
    try {
        OnDatePickerDoneButtonClickedListener act = (OnDatePickerDoneButtonClickedListener) getActivity();

    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Must implement OnDatePickerDoneButtonClickedListener");
    }
}


    public interface OnDatePickerDoneButtonClickedListener {
    void OnDatePickerDoneButtonClicked(String date);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    defaultDate = getArguments().getString(ARG_DEFAULT);

}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(defaultDate)) {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");;
        try {
            calendar.setTime(df.parse(new Date().toString()));
            Log.d("first", defaultDate + " -");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
        try {
            DateFormat df =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
            calendar.setTime(df.parse(defaultDate));
            Log.d("second", defaultDate + " -");
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            Log.d("third",defaultDate+" -");
        }
    }
    datePicker = new DatePicker(getActivity());

    datePicker.setCalendarViewShown(false);
    datePicker.setMaxDate(new Date().getTime()-1 * 24 * 3600 * 1000);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

//            String date =datePicker.getYear()+ "-"+ datePicker.getDayOfMonth() + "-" + (datePicker.getMonth() + 1)   ;
            int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
            int month = datePicker.getMonth();
            int year =  datePicker.getYear();

         final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(year, month, day);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
            String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
            OnDatePickerDoneButtonClickedListener act = (OnDatePickerDoneButtonClickedListener) getActivity();
            act.OnDatePickerDoneButtonClicked(date);
            dismiss();
        }
    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dismiss();
                }
            })
                    //.setTitle("Select date")
            .setView(datePicker);
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();

}
}
```

The `edittext` which i call the dialog to open the datepicker:

```
  birthday.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                               @Override
                               public void onClick(View v) {
                                   DatePickerDialog2 dialog = new DatePickerDialog2();
                                   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                   bundle.putString("dateAsText", birthday.getText().toString());
                                   dialog.setArguments(bundle);
                                   dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date_picker_frag");
                               }
                           });
```

Answer (score 0):

first implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener in your DatePickerDialog2 class then override onDateSet method in your DatePickerDialog2 class

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    String selDate = year + "-" + String.format("%02d", (monthOfYear+1)) + "-" + String.format("%02d", dayOfMonth);
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("selectedDate",selDate);
    getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
}
```

then in your activity class

```
mEtDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment picker = new DatePickerFragment();
            picker.setTargetFragment(OverviewFragment.this, ID_DATEPICKER_FRAGMENT);
            picker.show(getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(), "datePicker");
        }
    });
```

then override method **onActivityResult**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if((resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)){
        Bundle bundle=data.getExtras();
        String resultDate = bundle.getString("selectedDate","");
        mEtDate.setText(resultDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: and it tells me can't resolve the code you write in the edittext ?

Comment: there is no activity class?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private Calendar cal;
private int day;
private int month;
private int year;
EditText et;

cal = Calendar.getInstance();
day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
et.setInputType(0);
et.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
  hideSoftKeyboard(RegisterActivity.this);
  android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
  newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");

 }
});

public static class SelectDateFragment extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

 @Override
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
  int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
  int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
  return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
 }

 public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
  populateSetDate(yy, mm + 1, dd);
 }

 public String populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
  et.setText(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
  return (month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
 }

}
```

Comment: clicklistener and the datepicker are not in the same class